# Android AndEngine Boolean java logic issue

Tags: java, android, andengine

First I define the boolean

```
public boolean isPlaying = false;
```

then

```
                if (!isPlaying){
                    final Sprite ready = new Sprite(mCameraWidth/2 - (this.mgetReadyTextureRegion.getWidth() / 2), mCameraHeight/2 - (this.mgetReadyTextureRegion.getWidth() / 2), this.mgetReadyTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){    
                                mScene.detachChild(this);
                                isPlaying = true;
                            }
                            return true;
                       }
                    };
                }
```

then I have similar methods to spawn sprites

```
                if (isPlaying){
                         SpawnSprites();
                }
```

**My problem**:

I want first to have a `welcoming sprite` and when clicking on it, everything works fine. I do that by having a `boolean` called `isPlaying (**starting** false)`. When the activity start it is `false` so the `welcoming (ready) sprite` shows, and when you click on it, it should makes `isPlaying true` and `detaches it self` which will enable `SpawnSprites();`.

**Currently**:
The `welcoming ready sprite` detaches it self but the `spawnSprites();` doesn't function.

Using the `logcat`, I can see that `isPlaying` becomes true but the `spawnSprite();` doesn't work while it is `true` -,-, and if I do `isPlaying = true` from the first The `spawnSprite();` would function but the `welcoming ready` wont.

Comment: post your code where  SpawnSprites() method  is calling

Comment: ignore that .. I have                 if (isPlaying){
                         mScene.attachChild(player);
                }

Comment: It doesn't get attached, but if I remove isPLaying it get attached, I think it is java logic issue

Comment: i want to know when you calling  if (isPlaying){ mScene.attachChild(player); }  case..

Comment: It doesn't matter calling it before or aftter if(!isPLaying);, both of them are being called in the onCreateScene